# Datetimezone in python

Tags: python, date

In php im able to get the daylight savings info (the +02:00 or +01:00) given a time zone and a time, like this

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-09-01 17:16:32', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

result>> 2014-09-01 17:16:32+02:00
```

Im trying with this but is adding the two hours to the input date! I only want to add the +02:00/+01:00 to a given date without touch the input date:

```
madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
print datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 07, 50, 13, tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(madrid) 

result>> 2012-04-14 09:50:00+02:00
```

How can I do like the php code in python??

Thanks in advice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) you need to use localize for this;

```
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
>>> loc_dt = madrid.localize(datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 07, 50, 13))
>>> print loc_dt
2012-04-14 07:50:13+02:00
```

Comment: Many thanks asp!!
Im newbie in python, I was a bit stucked with all this datetimezones stuff in python. Now more cleared, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this print statement

```
print datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 14, 07, 50, 13, tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(madrid).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
```

It outputs:

```
2012-04-14 09:50:13+0200
```

Comment: No point for this, I dont want to convert the licalized time, What I wanted is to localize a native datetime, thanks anyway